# Biblatex bilbiography error: Undefined control sequence. <to be read again> \edef \blx@tempa {745\x {00AD}\bibrangedash 771} l.423 \

Tags: biblatex

Using Texmaker 5.02 and `biblatex`, I am getting this error when I try to compile a document:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<to be read again> \edef \blx@tempa {745\x {00AD}\bibrangedash 771}
l.423
```

l.423 is where `\printbibliography` appears; if I delete that, there is no error.

As I understand it, the error message is saying that one of the bib strings contains a character that is making things go wrong. Unicode 00AD is a soft hyphen. I cannot find one (it is not between the only occurrences of 745 and 771 in the bib file)

Also, here's the really weird thing: the document was compiling fine; then I added some references (to the document and the bib file). Then it started giving this error message. But if I delete the added references, it now still gives the error message.

I am very puzzled. Any ideas?

Comment: What character is there between `745` and `771` in your `.bib` file? (Keep in mind that a hyphen characters may look alike in some fonts, you can paste the text to https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html to see the Unicode entities.) Since `.bib` entries are read by LaTeX via the intermediate `.bbl` file, some errors may persist even if the `.bib` file was changed or the offending citation was removed from the main document. In cases like this you can only say conclusively if the error goes away if you delete the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` files and recompile from scratch.

Comment: It's a normal hyphen. I have deleted it and retyped it several times. I've tried deleting that field entirely. And between each attempt, I've been deleting all the .aux, .bbl etc files. Same problem recurs.

Comment: Please try to isolate the problematic `.bib` entry and post it here together with a short example document citing it, so we can have a closer look at the issue.

Comment: Note that U+00AD, the soft hyphen, is invisible. So you may have the invisible soft hyphen followed by a real hyphen, see e.g. https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?745%C2%AD-771. If you *only* delete and retype the hyphen, you don't actually clear the soft hyphen. Delete and retype the whole field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<to be read again> \edef \blx@tempa {745\x 
                                           {00AD}\bibrangedash 771}
l.24 \end
         {document}
```

can be reproduced with the following MWE (the problem does not appear without `safeinputenc,`, but the `.bbl` data will not be quite right in that case either)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, safeinputenc, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  journal = {J. Imp. Things},
  volume  = {47},
  pages   = {745­-771},
  date    = {1980},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[If you copy and paste the contents of the `pages` fields](https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?745%C2%AD-771) to https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html [the site responds with](https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html?745%C2%AD-771)

```
  U+0037 DIGIT SEVEN     7
  U+0034 DIGIT FOUR     4
  U+0035 DIGIT FIVE     5
  U+00ad SOFT HYPHEN     &shy; \-
  U+002d HYPHEN-MINUS     -
  U+0037 DIGIT SEVEN     7
  U+0037 DIGIT SEVEN     7
  U+0031 DIGIT ONE     1
```

There is an invisible U+00AD soft hyphen directly in front of the normal hyphen.

If you only delete and retype the visible hyphen in the example, you'll miss the invisible soft hyphen. Delete and retype the whole field. It should be

```
pages = {745-771},
```

without the U+00AD. After that remove the `.aux`, `.bbl` and `.bcf` files and recompile.

Comment: Thanks! This has solved it -- with some embarrassment . . .

I did, at some point, figure that it must be an invisible character and retype the entire field. But I must have neglected to remove the .aux etc files on that iteration. So I still got the error. I should have been more systematic about my troubleshooting. Thanks and sorry to waste time!

Oh, and that unicode converter is brilliant. Thanks.

Comment: @Quiddity If the answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it to show that the issue is resolved. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I thought I had! Man, what a day.